# CLisp: Collecting all keywords supported

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I tend to use Notepad++ as editor to learn lisp and this helps me with prompting the keywords as I type them on editor. But not all the keywords are enlisted in its language plugin.

I want to add those keywords into it. Is there some command in lisp that it lists its keywords or some source that contains these keywords/function templates etc that I can just add them by pasting them in NP++ plugin.

Manually accomplishing this will be very time consuming.

Comment: What do you mean by "keyword" here? Literally, Lisp keywords (symbols living in the `keyword` package)? Or do you mean stuff exported by the `common-lisp` package (basically, the ANSI common lisp language?

Comment: @Dirk : I meant all those words/symbols that are common across most of lisp implementations.

Comment: You wrote clisp in the title, but you didn't tag it with [tag:clisp].  Is there actually anything in this question that's specific to the GNU CLISP implementation of the Common Lisp language?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor : I have been using GNU Clisp so I mentioned it. But I think its not very specific as well. It could be seen both ways I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, that you want the symbols of the COMMON-LISP package, you can use

```
(do-external-symbols (sym :common-lisp) 
  (print sym))
```

to collect all symbols exposed by the COMMON-LISP package. According to the [ANSI standard](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_aba.htm),

> The COMMON-LISP package has as external symbols those symbols enumerated in the figures in Section 1.9 (Symbols in the COMMON-LISP Package), and no others"

so the above should give you exactly the stuff defined by the ANSI common lisp language (and nothing else).

To get a sorted list, try

```
(let (result) 
  (do-external-symbols (sym :common-lisp) 
    (push sym result)) 
  (sort result #'string<))
```

on the REPL.

Comment: Note that that will give you a lot of things that you might not want special highlighting for.  E.g., you probably don't want to highlight `list`, `t`, `nil`, etc., everywhere.  It might be useful to only highlight those that satisfy `special-operator-p` or has a binding as a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can just copy-paste the symbols from CLHS: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/X_AllSym.htm

Comment: yes..that's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks. Is there some similar info for function templates ?

Comment: What do you mean by "function templates"? Declarations of functions, i.e. their names along with names of their parameters? I don't know about a single page with that. I guess it shouldn't be difficult to write a script which would scrap this by following links on the page with list of all symbols.

Comment: `defun` is in that list, as are all the lambda list keywords (&allow-other-keys
&aux
&body
&environment
&key
&optional
&rest
&whole).